# Read txt file and put in list with python

Tags: python

I have a file with text with only 0's and 1's. No space between them. Example:

0101110

1110111

I would like to read a character at a time and place them as a single element in a list of integers.

**My code:**

```
intlist = []

with open('arq.txt', 'r') as handle:
for line in handle:
    if not line.strip():
        continue

    values = map(int, line.split())
    intlist.append(values)

print intlist
handle.close()
```

My result:

[[101110], [1110111]]

Like if I transform the 0101110 in intlist = [0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1]. (without '\n')

Comment: I think the answer already solved your problem, Am i wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you have is numbers and linefeeds, you can just read the file, remove the linefeeds, map the resulting string to integers, and turn that into a `list`:

```
with open('arq.txt') as handle:
    intlist = list(map(int, handle.read().replace('\n', '')))

print intlist
```

Comment: @ialsafid - Note that `map()` already returns a `list` in Python 2, so you can omit the `list()` call if you don't plan on porting this to Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

You just need two changes. The first is, when you're making `values`, you need to take each individual character of the line, instead of the entire line at once:
`values = [int(x) for x in line.strip() if x]`

Now, if you run this code on its own, you'll get `[[1, 0, ...], [1, 1, ...]]`. The issue is that if you call `list.append` with another list as an argument, you'll just add the list as an element. You're looking for the `list.extend` method instead:

`intlist.extend(values)`

Your final code would be:

```
intlist = []

with open('arq.txt', 'r') as handle:
    for line in handle:
        if not line.strip():
            continue

        values = [int(x) for x in line.strip() if x]
        intlist.extend(values)

    print intlist
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Ty.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you can do it. You also don't need to use `handle.close()` the context manager handles closing the file for you.

```
intlist = []

with open('arq.txt', 'r') as handle:
    for line in handle:
        if not line.strip():
            continue
        intlist[:] += [int(char) for i in line.split() for char in i]

print(intlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use *strip()* for delete *\n* and *filter* with *bool* for deleting empty strings:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    lines = map(lambda x: x.strip(), filter(bool, f))
    print [int(value) for number in lines for value in number]
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility:

```
intlist = []

with open('arq.txt', 'r') as handle:
    for line in handle:
        for ch in line.strip():
            intlist.append (ch)

print intlist
```