# How do I read CSV files and put it in list with Python?

Tags: python, csv

Sorry, I'm a noob.
I have a csv file like this

```
customerID , gender , ...
5575-GNVDE , Female , ...
9763-GRSKD , Male   , ...
```

I want put "customerID" column in list

ex:

```
print(customerID)
```

like

```
[5575-GNVDE, 9763-GRSKD , ...]
```

I already write the code

```py
csvFile = open("WA_Fn-UseC_-Telco-Customer-Churn.csv", "r")
reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
# create list
customerID = []
for item in reader:
    # ignore first line
    if reader.line_num == 1:
        continue
    customerID += item[0]

print(customerID)
csvFile.close()
```

it show like this

```
['5', '5', '7', '5', '-', 'G', 'N', 'V', 'D', 'E','9', '7', '6', '3', '-', 'G', 'R', 'S', 'K', 'D',...]
```

I already read:

- [Create a csv file with python and put in nested list to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45521744/create-a-csv-file-with-python-and-put-in-nested-list-to-it)
- [Read txt file and put in list with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36522296/read-txt-file-and-put-in-list-with-python)
- [How do I read and write CSV files with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585078/how-do-i-read-and-write-csv-files-with-python)
- [Reading rows from a CSV file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428318/reading-rows-from-a-csv-file-in-python)
- [Python import csv to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662571/python-import-csv-to-list)
- [How do I read and write CSV files with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585078/how-do-i-read-and-write-csv-files-with-python)

Please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: use `pandas` library. the method is `pandas.read_csv`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using this:

```
    customerID += item[0]
```

But that doesn't do what you think it does. `customerID` is a list and you're using the add operator on it, so Python tries to interpret `item[0]` as a list as well, which is a `str`, but can be considered a list of characters - so that's exactly what gets added.

Instead, use:

```
    customerID.append(item[0])
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
    customerID += [item[0]]
```